# Bootstrap, allowing content to be responsive/flexible regardless of html layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a "mostly" functional system that works right now as a CMS: The user goes into an editor and chooses from one of four templates. Within the template they click on a section where they can add images, text or both.

I have a preview screen that shows them what they're making but the issue is that they can create something here where it looks like the image is fitting the space but when it's saved and shown on a huge display it creeps to the top and has a ton of white space below.

So I'm using TinyMCE and when the user saves the info it's saved as HTML in the database, and on my display page (code below) I have that database-driven html coming through a JSON object.

My thing is this: How can I use existing Bootstrap to make sure that regardless of which layout I'm using below (either full width, 2 half width, or a half width with 2 quarter-height half divs) the content within can be more responsive and flexible? I'm trying to get the displayed content to match more closely to what they see on the editor so that regardless of what computer they use to make it, it will be more responseive on the display

This is all of my css and html

```
         html,
            body {
              height: 100vh;
              width: 100vw;
              overflow: hidden;
            }

            iframe{
              height:100% !important;
              width:100% !important;
            }

            .middle p{
              max-height:100%;
            }

            .my-container {
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
              justify-content: center;
              height: 100vh;
              width:100vw;
            }

            .my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
            .my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
              background-color: #778899  ;
              color: white;
              text-align: center;
            }

            .my-container>.middle {
              flex-grow: 1;
              padding:30px;
              /*background-image: url('images/bg_green.svg');*/
              background-size: cover;
            }

            .my-container>.middle>* {
            }

    <div class="container-fluid my-container d-flex h-100">

        <div class="row top">
            <?php include 'banner.php'?>
        </div>

        <div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">
            <!-- Full Page Divs -->
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="fullColumn">
                <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style="height: 100%; ">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Full Page Divs -->

            <!-- Half Page Divs -->
            <div class="col-lg-6 leftColumn " id="leftColumn" style="align-items: center;">

                <div class="leftContent" id="leftContent" style=" margin:auto; height: 100%; ">        

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 rightColumn" id="rightColumn">

              <div class="rightContent" id="rightContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- End Half Page Divs -->

            <!-- Quarter Page Divs -->

            <!-- Left -->
            <div class="col-lg-6"  id="leftColumnQtr">
              <div class="row" style="height:50%; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:100%;">
                    <div  id="topLeftContent" style=" height: 100%; ">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row" style="height:50%; padding-top: 15px;">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:100%;">
                    <div id="bottomLeftContent" style=" height: 100%;">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" id="rightColumnQtrHalf" >
                <div id="rightQtrContent" style=" height: 100%; ">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- right -->
            <div class="col-lg-6" id="rightColumnQtr">
                <div id="leftQtrContent" style="height: 100%;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" id="leftColumnQtrHalf" >
              <div class="row" style="height:50%; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:100%;">
                  <div id="topRightContent" style=" height: 100%;">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row" style="height:50%; padding-top: 15px;">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:100%;">
                  <div id="bottomRightContent" style=" height: 100%;">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Quarter Page Divs -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Row Middle -->

        <div class="row bottom">
            <?php include 'ticker.php';?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you have a specific example of an issue or are you just trying to preemptively make sure nothing goes awry? If TinyMCE is stripping inline styles (so users can't hard-code widths) then you should be mostly fine I would think. The only thing I would recommend would be to make sure `img`'s don't overflow the columns by adding something like `img {max-width: 100%; }`. Everything else should just be text content which should just wrap.

Comment: I'm not positive but I think it's stripping the styles. However, if they add an image and resize it to be 500x500, then that's the height/width that is used in rendering. I'd like it to treat the images more responsively. Let me try the max-width thing and get back to you real quick

Comment: That seems to make the images at least scale smaller but they seem to break my row-top and row-bottom elements. Is there a way I can make sure they stay contained between those two rows?

Comment: Do those rows have columns? In the code above I see `<div class="row top"><?php include 'banner.php'?></div>` so I am unsure if **a)** that is one of the rows you are talking about and **b)** what markup is contained in banner.php

Comment: Yes that is the top row I'm talking about and it contains a main div of col-lg-12, which within contains col-lg-3, col-lg-6 and col-lg3 in a row

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on what I could get about what you wanted. One thing I'd Strongly recommend is not setting width and height before the initial layout is structured. once the skeleton is ready you can start messing with it.

NOTE: I used bootstrap 4.2.1 for testing this.
"//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"

-- SOLUTION --

I removed all your styles to make things simpler, the styles below are for display purpose only. Feel free to play with it.

```
<style>
    div {
        background-color: #00333333;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px;
        min-height: 20px;
    }

    div.row {
        background-color: #ff000033;
    }

</style>
```

HTML code

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row top">
        <h2>something in top</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Full Page Divs -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1> FULL PAGE </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Full Page Divs -->

        <!-- Half Page Divs -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1> left half </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1> right half </h1>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Half Page Divs -->

        <!-- Quarter Page Divs -->

        <!-- Left -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="leftColumnQtr">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h1>topLeftContent</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h1>bottomLeftContent</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6" id="rightColumnQtrHalf">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1>Right half</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- right -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="rightColumnQtrHalf">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1>Left half</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6" id="leftColumnQtr">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h1>top right Content</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h1>bottom right Content</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Quarter Page Divs -->
        <!-- BONUS: may be this is what you wanted too -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h1>top Left Content</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h1>bottom Left Content</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6" id="rightColumnQtrHalf">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h1>Right half</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h1>Left half</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h1>top right Content</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h1>bottom right Content</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- End Row Middle -->
    <div class="row bottom">
        <h2>something in bottom</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is what you intended.